# Compare images using sikuli in java

Tags: java, sikuli

im using sikuli-api 1.0.1 in java. The current problem is that I want to use the matching algo for a given image instead of a screen. The code which works is:

```
ScreenRegion s = new DesktopScreenRegion();
Target imageTarget = new ImageTarget(new File("someImage"));
ScreenRegion r = s.find(imageTarget);
```

Instead of using the ScreenRegion I would like to use a given image (File/BufferedImage). 
Any ideas how to do it? I dont want to click on the image etc. I just want to use sikulis algo to check if the target is inside the image.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to create your own `ScreenRegion` implementation. Replace `DesktopScreenRegion` by an `ImageScreenRegion` which implements `ScreenRegion`.

`ScreenRegion` interface is pretty limited in terms of external classes implementations. It seems you'll just have to implement an `ImageScreen` and an `ImageScreenLocation` (easy as pie)

Look at the [`SreenRegion` sources](https://bitbucket.org/doubleshow/sikuli-api/src/2899f8b3c4f5effac915478a00815075caf50446/src/main/java/org/sikuli/api/ScreenRegion.java?at=master)

Comment: I went the simpler way and implemented the Screen Interface.

Comment: You're right. That's much simpler, and easy with the `DefaultScreenRegion` constructor with a `Screen` argument.